# missing values in table generated from database query

Tags: php

I created a table in MySQL with one item in it, copied another php page on my site already pulling from the database and tried to modify it to pull from my 'gigs' table.  It's not working and I'm close to going insane :)

Here's my PHP:

```
<div class="span12">
<h3>View & Manage Your Gigs</h3>
 <table class="table table-striped">
<tr>
<th>Gig ID</th>
<th>Gig Name</th>
<th>Customer</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Fee</th>    
<th>Status</th>
<th>Manage</th>
</tr>
<?php
$cnt = ORM::for_table('gigs')->where('gid', $cid)->count();
if ($cnt>0){
    $items = ORM::for_table('gigs')->raw_query($query)->find_many();
    $i='0';
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $i++;
        $gigid = $item['gigid'];
        $gig_name = $item['gig_name'];
        $gig_customer = $item['gig_customer'];
        $gig_date = $item['gig_date'];
        $gig_fee = $item['gig_fee'];
        $status = $item['gig_status'];

        if ($status=='Booked'){
            $st="<a class=\"btn btn-danger btn-small\" href=\"invoice$ext?_cmd=$gigid\">".$_L['pay_now']."</a>";
        } else {
            $st="<a class=\"btn btn-primary btn-small\" href=\"invoice$ext?_cmd=$gigid\">".$_L['view']."</a>";
        }

        $ext = EXT;
        echo "<tr>
<td>$gigid</td>
<td>$gig_name</td>
<td>$gig_customer</td>
<td>$gig_date</td>
<td>$gig_fee</td>   
 <td>$status</td>
  <td>$st</td>
</tr>";
    }

}

?>
</table>
<?php  echo  $paginate['contents']; ?> 
</div>
```

When I view source on my page, it is creating the table headings, but the td doesn't get created and of course there is no data showing - just headings..

Any ideas?

Error reporting gave me:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'gid' in 'where clause'' in /home/content/s/t/o/stolzillusions/html/gigs/lib/d.f.php:387
Stack trace:
#0 /home/content/s/t/o/stolzillusions/html/gigs/lib/d.f.php(387): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /home/content/s/t/o/stolzillusions/html/gigs/lib/d.f.php(1539): ORM::_execute('SELECT COUNT(*)...', Array, 'default')
#2 /home/content/s/t/o/stolzillusions/html/gigs/lib/d.f.php(549): ORM->_run()
#3 /home/content/s/t/o/stolzillusions/html/gigs/lib/d.f.php(658): ORM->find_one()
#4 /home/content/s/t/o/stolzillusions/html/gigs/lib/d.f.php(610): ORM->_call_aggregate_db_function('count', '*')
#5 /home/content/s/t/o/stolzillusions/html/gigs/cp/views/bmsapp/gig-list.tpl.php(19): ORM->count()
#6 /home/content/s/t/o/stolzillusions/html/gigs/cp/gig-list.php(4): require('/home/content/s...')
#7 {main} thrown in /home/content/s/t/o/stolzillusions/html/gigs/lib/d.f.php on line 387`
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `<tbody>` ?

Comment: Can you echo out the variables without the markup? Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php tag error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: In the `foreach` loop, can you do a `print_r($item)` and see if you are getting any result. What is the value of `$cnt`?

Comment: Error reporting definitely gave me something

Answer (score 1):

You haven't set a value to the $query variable or I missing something?

Comment: Good catch. May be the `$query` variable is set from other code which he did not put here.

Comment: Yes , although from the error reporting  the problem seems to start at the $cnt declaration

Comment: I see a variable which is not declared in the provided code? How 's that critique? This is probably the cause of the problem.

Comment: Found where Query is defined:

<?php
require 'boot.php';
$query = "SELECT gigid, gig_name, gig_customer, gig_date, gig_fee, status FROM gigs ORDER BY gig_date";
require ("views/$gTheme/gig-list.tpl.php");

Comment: If  you don't get any errors than you ll probably don't get any results from your query. Try to echo the $i variable to see if you have iterations in your look. Also the above query will fetch all gigs not only for one customer

Answer (score 0):

`var_dump` `print_r($items)` before the **foreach** loop. You will get exact idea whether you are getting data or not.

Let me know in case of further issues.

Comment: No go, loaded a blank page.

Comment: Please use `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); ?>`. Then refresh the page please.

Comment: @topher also `var_dump` `$cnt` before `if ($cnt>0){`. You will get to know that how many rows counted.

Comment: *update* I tried:  print_r ($cnt);
And it returned:  1

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$cnt = ORM::for_table('gigs')->where('gid', $cid)->count();
```

try

```
$cnt = ORM::for_table('gigs')->where('gigid', $cid)->count();
```

**Edit:** according to your comment it would actually be this:

```
$cnt = ORM::for_table('gigs')->where('gig_customer', $cid)->count();
```

Comment: No difference I'm afraid

Comment: Really? There's this in error output. `Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 ` **`Unknown column 'gid'`** `in 'where clause''`. You sure you saved your file and deployed it? Maybe there's something similar in code. Search for `'gid'`.

Comment: I'm still not seeing it output data, but at least it's not spitting out any error messages now

Comment: BTW: What's `$cid` and what's `$cnt` value after first select executes?

Comment: So I think cid is supposed to be customer id.  I found this declared in another file:  $cid=$_SESSION['cid'];   (and I am logged in as the customer that the table items are associated to)

Answer (score 0):

I got it!  It was indeed $Query.

When I changed this

```
$items = ORM::for_table('gigs')->raw_query($query)->find_many();
```

To this:

```
$items = ORM::for_table('gigs')->find_many();
```